# How to set default scope for Personal Access Token by Laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-passport

According to Laravel Passport documentations, i can set default scope to tokens using,

```
Passport::setDefaultScope([
    'my-scope'
]);
```

But this does not seems to be working with Personal Access Tokens. I checked the documentation to see if this method does not work with Personal Access Tokens. Did not find anything.

So the questions is, **How can i set default scope for personal access tokens ?**

**Note:** I am doing this with vue.js. In case it is relevant.